# Put array as argument and read its value

Tags: c, arrays

I am scanning for values using function .

```
int **array(int * counter) {
    int **vrat;
    int max = 5; 
    int index = 0;
    int i;
    vrat = malloc(max*sizeof(int*));
    for ( i = 0; i < max ; i++) {
        vrat[i] = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
    }
    int x;
    int y;
    char c;
    while (scanf("%d%c%d", &x, &c, &y) != EOF) {
        vrat[index][0] = x;
        vrat[index][1] = y;
        index++;
    }
    *counter = index;
    return vrat;
}
```

and calling it in main to return the array, which works .

```
int main()
{
    int counter=0;
    int **mej;
    int gg;
    mej = array(&counter);
    int i;
    gg = pocet(mej, &counter);

    return 0;
}
```

what is bothering my mnd is "pocet" function , i am passing an array in it and want to print its value . but it always print undefined numbers
Function looks like this

```
int pocet(int array[][2],int *counter) {
    int poc = 0;
    int i;
    for ( i =0; i < *counter ;i++) {
          printf("cislo = %d", array[i][0]);    
    }
    return poc;
}
```

as you can see , it has  static 2nd dimension , how can i make this work?

Comment: Your first `malloc()` is wrong.

Comment: What's `mej`? How and where is it declared?

Comment: @Johnyb Check my answer. Does it solve your problem of printing *random* numbers?

Comment: no it does not , as i said the problem function is "pocet" which somehow does not recognize array that i input as argument and so print random numbers instead of its value

Answer (score 3):

1. You are allocating space for `5` pointers, you should multiply by the size of a pointer and not the size of an `int`, like this

   ```
   vrat = malloc(max * sizeof(int *));
   /*                             ^ pointer */
   ```

   Although you can completely avoid the mistake by multiplying by the size of the pointer type like this

   ```
   vrat = malloc(max * sizeof(*vrat));
   ```

   and ALWAYS check that `malloc()` has not returned `NULL` before actually using the pointer.
2. Also, don't compare `scanf()` to `EOF` since it's very unlikely to get an `EOF` before an input error because it requires explicit input from the user, instead do this

   ```
   while(scanf("%d%c%d", &x, &c, &y) == 3)
   ```
3. The return type of your function should match that of the returned object, in this case `int **`, change the function signature to

   ```
   int **array(int *content)
   ```

Comment: Also note that the return type of `array` is wrong; `int` vs `int**`.

Comment: Style: "multiply by the size of a pointer" is one way.  IMO, better code is to multiply based on the variable `vrat`, than the type `int *`: `vrat = malloc(sizeof *vrat * max);`.

Comment: thanks , fixed prblem but it still throws undefined numbers

Comment: What is the `%c` in the middle of the format? If it's used to skip spaces it doesn't make sense because the `%d` already does.

Comment: i am inputing "number:number" char is for :

Comment: If you discard it you can simple use `"%d:%d"`! And even if you don't, if it returns `2` then surely `":"` was the separator.

Answer (score 1):

1. `vrat = malloc(max*sizeof(int*));`

   How do you know whether the memory successfully got allocated or not?

   Always check the pointer returned by `malloc & family` functions for equivalence with `NULL` to avoid possible `SegFault`.

---

2. `while (scanf("%d%c%d", &x, &c, &y) != EOF)`

   What if there's matching failure for `c`? Then `scanf` will return `1` and `while` will still go for iteration even if `scanf` could not store values in `c` and `y`.

   So always compare `scanf` return value with no. of arguments instead of `EOF`

---

3. ```
   while (scanf("%d%c%d", &x, &c, &y) != EOF) {
       vrat[index][0] = x;
       vrat[index][1] = y;
       index++;
   }
   ```

   Here what if `index >= max`?

   Since you have allocated memory for only `max` integer pointers you must not try to access the memory beyond the allocated chunk.

   Solution: Change `while` condition to

   ```
   while ((scanf("%d%c%d", &x, &c, &y) == 3) && (index < max))
   ```

---

So the correct code snippet would be:

```
vrat = malloc(max*sizeof(int*));
if(!vrat)
{
    printf("vrat: malloc failed!\n");
    exit(1);
}

for ( i = 0; i < max ; i++) {
    vrat[i] = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
    if(!vrat[i])
    {
        printf("vrat[%d]: malloc failed!\n", i);
        exit(1);
    }
}

int x;
int y;
char c;
while ((scanf("%d%c%d", &x, &c, &y) == 3) && (index < max)) {
    vrat[index][0] = x;
    vrat[index][1] = y;
    index++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An `int**` is not an `int[][2]`. The first is a pointer to pointers to `int` while the second (as an argument) is a pointer to `int[2]`. You cannot convert between the two the way you tried. You should have gotten a compiler warning/error about this.

The easiest way to fix this is to have `pocet` take an `int**` as the first argument. Fix the issues others have mentioned as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `int **vrat;`
When you do malloc, you need to use `int **` or `int *` and not `int`